# What is the best way to segregate the data alphabetically using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

What is the best way to segregate the data alphabetically using SQL?

I would like to divide the data into 3 parts based on starting character of data in some columns??

Comment: Sounds extremely straightforward. Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: Do you know the boundaries for the 3 parts in advance? E.g. (A~G, H~O, P~Z)

Comment: What should I use? Like statement??

Comment: @Dan Grossman: Please enlighten us.

Comment: I would like to divide the data into 3 parts say (A~G, H~O, P~Z)!

Comment: yeah you are right Sourav you can use Like operator there to complete this task...

Comment: I dont think this is the best way to do that!I think regular expression is the best way to do that!!What do you say??

Comment: `LIKE 'something%' ` is much faster than any Regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use this:

```
select *
from your_table
where your_column between 'A' and 'G';
```

Comment: Note: `'George' > 'G'` => `'George' is NOT BETWEEN 'A' AND 'G'`. So, this will NOT include any rows with `'George'` or `'Graham'` or any word starting with `G` (except **and only** `'G'`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEX_LIKE statement to get the result.

Example:

```
-- For Range [A--G]
SELECT target_col
FROM   target_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( target_col, '^[A-G].$' ) ;

-- For Range [H--O]
SELECT target_col
FROM   target_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( target_col, '^[H-O].$' ) ;

-- For Range [P--Z]
SELECT target_col
FROM   target_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( target_col, '^[P-Z].$' ) ;
```

Comment: can you please help me in understanding how this query would process in Oracle??

Comment: I am sorry Sourav, But this is an Oracle statement. You can get further help of `REGEXP_LIKE` on http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
-- For Range [A--G]

SELECT target_col
FROM   target_table
WHERE  target_col >= 'A'
  AND  target_col < 'H'
```

If there is a simple index on `target_col`, the query will probably use it.

Comment: Which is best of the three solutions??

Comment: I realized that substr is not required to do the filter, so ypercube solution and mine are the same.

Comment: @SouravM: Why don't you try the solutions you have (and time them)?